# PERL : I take mday value from locatime as below , . How can I subtract 1 from mday which I take from localtime

Tags: perl, date, time, timezone, nls

PERL : I take mday value from locatime as below ,now I want value of day before yesterday . How can I subtract 1 from mday which I take from localtime

```
my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime();
my $part = "P".$mday;

print "Today value is $part \n";

my $part_yes = "P".$mday - $num;

print "$part_yes \n";
```

Comment: my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime(); 

my $part = "P".$mday;

print "Today value is $part \n";

my $part_yes = "P".$mday - $num;

print "$part_yes \n";

Comment: if you only need `$mday`, ignore the other values with: `my $mday = ( localtime )[3];`

Comment: In one place, you say you want 2 days earlier. In another place, you say you want one day earlier. Which is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using DateTime:

```perl
my $dt =
   DateTime
   ->now( time_zone => 'local' )
   ->set_time_zone('floating')  # Do this when working with dates.
   ->truncate( to => 'days' );  # Optional.

$dt->subtract( days => 2 );

my $yesterday = $dt->day;
```

---

DateTime is pretty heavy, and it seems people asking date-time questions invariably come back and say "core modules only!", so here's a solution using only core modules.

```perl
use Time::Local qw( timegm );

# Create an timestamp with the same date in UTC as the one local one.
my $epoch = timegm(0, 0, 0, ( localtime() )[3,4,5]);

# We can now do date arithmetic without having to worry about DST switches.
$epoch -= 2 * 24*60*60;

my $yesterday = ( gmtime($epoch) )[3] + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my $now = time(); # time as seconds since 1970-01-01
my $day_ago = $now - 24*60*60;

my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime($day_ago);
my $part = "P".$mday;
```

**WARNING** (ikegami comment): Not all days have 24 hours. This can produce a result that's 0, 1 or 2 days earlier

https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/time
https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime

Comment: "day before yesterday" should be `2*24*60*60`

Comment: Not all days have 24 hours. This can produce a result that's 0, 1 or 2 days earlier

Comment: @ikegami I have added DST warning.  The simple and module-less recipe may be useful in many **but not all** situations.

Comment: I  can't think of a single situation where it's useful, so saying it's useful in many situations might be overstating things a bit.